MPI_Iprobe does not receive new events after START_LELECT_ST tag is processed
I am building a Satellite (ST) to Ground Stations (GS) distributed communication system, and I am at the point where I am implementing leader election among satellites (in a ring) and among ground stations (in an undirected graph). The election processes do indeed finish, upon which point the coordinator process (rank n-1) sends out the ST leader to all GS processes and the GS leader to all ST processes respectively.
Everything works fine for the ST election and message passing, but for some reason, when the coordinator sends out the GS_ELECT event to all ST processes after the GS leader election, the ST processes do not receive the event. I tried logging the probe's tag, and it is always START_LELECT_ST and no matter what event is sent afterward, it just never changes the status of the probe, neither with GS_LEADER nor with TERMINATE.
I cannot figure out why this is happening since if I am not mistaken, MPI_Probe and MPI_Iprobe should be seeing the pending new events and grabbing their tags.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "common/constants.h"
#include "common/event_payloads.h"
#include "coordinator/coordinator.h"
#include "common/mpi_datatypes.h"
#include "ground_station/ground_station.h"
#include <mpi/mpi.h>
#include <string.h>
 
#include "common/temp_metrics.h"
#include "satellite/satellite.h"
 
#define CONNECT_ACK_TOTAL(x) (((x - 1)/2) - 1)
const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 256;
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size, color;
    MPI_Comm comm_group;
 
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
 
    // Validate and get N from command line argument
    if (argc != 3) {
        if (rank == 0) {
            printf("Usage: mpirun -np <N+1> %s <N> <input file>\n", argv[0]);
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 1;
    }
    const int n = atoi(argv[1]) + 1;
    if (n <= 0 || size != n) {
        if (rank == 0) {
            printf("Invalid arguments. N must be positive and total processes (N+1) must match.\n");
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Assign ranks to groups based on their position relative to N
    if (rank == n - 1) {
        color = COORDINATOR_GROUP_ID;
    } else if (rank < (n - 1) / 2) {
        color = SATELLITE_GROUP_ID; // processes 0 to N/2-1
    } else {
        color = GROUND_STATION_GROUP_ID; // processes N/2 to N-1
    }
 
    // Create communicator groups
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, rank, &comm_group);
 
    // create custom MPI data types and commit them so they can be used
    MPI_Datatype connect_datatype = connect_event_datatype();
    MPI_Datatype add_status_datatype = add_status_event_datatype();
    MPI_Datatype coords_datatype = coordinates_datatype();
    MPI_Datatype st_add_coords_datatype = add_st_coords_event_datatype(coords_datatype);
    MPI_Datatype gs_add_coords_datatype = add_gs_coords_event_datatype(coords_datatype);
    MPI_Datatype st_add_metric_datatype = add_st_metric_event_datatype();
    MPI_Datatype st_lelect_probe_datatype = st_lelect_probe_event_datatype();
    MPI_Datatype st_lelect_reply_datatype = st_lelect_reply_event_datatype();
    MPI_Type_commit(&connect_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&add_status_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&st_add_coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&gs_add_coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&st_add_metric_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&st_lelect_probe_datatype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&st_lelect_reply_datatype);
 
    // Identify group information within each group
    int group_rank, group_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm_group, &group_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm_group, &group_size);
 
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 1;
    }
 
    // Parse input file if we are the coordinator
    if (rank == n - 1) {
        char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
 
        //todo move to coordinator
        int connect_ack_count = 0;
        MPI_Status status;
 
        while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
            char event[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
            // read line by line
            // Remove trailing newline character
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
            // Extract information based on the line type
            sscanf(line, "%s", event); // Read event type
 
            const int is_connect_event = strcmp(event, "CONNECT");
 
            if (is_connect_event == 0) {
                gs_connect event_data = parse_connect_event(line);
                // send CONNECT to gs_rank
                MPI_Send(&event_data, 1, connect_datatype, event_data.gs_rank, CONNECT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
 
            if (is_connect_event != 0) {
                // found different event, so we wait for n/2 ack if needed
                while (connect_ack_count < CONNECT_ACK_TOTAL(n)) {
                    // receive ACK events for CONNECT sends
                    MPI_Recv((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ACK, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    connect_ack_count++;
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
 
            printf("parsing %s\n", event);
 
            // parse other events after CONNECT events have finished
            if (strcmp(event, "ADD_STATUS") == 0) {
                st_add_status event_data = parse_add_status_event(line);
                MPI_Send(&event_data, 1, add_status_datatype, event_data.st_rank, ADD_STATUS, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            } else if (strcmp(event, "ADD_ST_COORDINATES") == 0) {
                st_add_coords event_data = parse_st_add_coords_event(line);
                MPI_Send(&event_data, 1, st_add_coords_datatype, event_data.st_rank, ADD_ST_COORDINATES,
                         MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            } else if (strcmp(event, "ADD_METRIC") == 0) {
                st_add_metric event_data = parse_st_add_metric_event(line);
                MPI_Send(&event_data, 1, st_add_metric_datatype, event_data.st_rank, ADD_METRIC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            } else if (strcmp(event, "ADD_GS_COORDINATES") == 0) {
                gs_add_coords event_data = parse_gs_add_coords_event(line);
                MPI_Send(&event_data, 1, gs_add_coords_datatype, event_data.gs_rank, ADD_GS_COORDINATES,
                         MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            } else if (strcmp(event, "STATUS_CHECK") == 0) {
                // Handle other line types as needed
            } else if (strcmp(event, "AVG_EARTH_TEMP") == 0) {
                // Handle other line types as needed
            } else if (strcmp(event, "SYNC") == 0) {
                // Handle other line types as needed
            } else if (strcmp(event, "PRINT") == 0) {
                // Handle other line types as needed
            } else if (strcmp(event, "START_LELECT_ST") == 0) {
                //todo: replace with mpi_scatter probably to improve network utilization
                for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1) / 2; i++) {
                    //printf("sending start elect to st %d\n", i);
                    MPI_Send((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, i, START_LELECT_ST, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
 
                int st_leader_rank;
                // wait for leader id
                MPI_Recv(&st_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, LELECT_ST_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                // forward to all GS processes with broadcast ig
                for (int i = (n - 1) / 2; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    //printf("sending st leader rank to GS %d\n", i);
                    MPI_Send(&st_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, i, ST_LEADER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            } else if (strcmp(event, "START_LELECT_GS") == 0) {
                for (int i = (n - 1) / 2; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    //printf("sending start gs elect to GS %d\n", i);
                    MPI_Send((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, i, START_LELECT_GS, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
 
                int gs_leader_rank;
                // wait for leader id
                MPI_Recv(&gs_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, LELECT_GS_DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                // account for GS communicator size
                gs_leader_rank += (n - 1) / 2;
                printf("---> coordinator got %d gs leader\n", gs_leader_rank);
                // forward gs rank to all ST processes
                for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1) / 2; i++) {
                    printf("sending gs leader (%d) to ST %d\n", gs_leader_rank, i);
                    MPI_Send(&gs_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, i, GS_LEADER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            } else {
                // if event is TERMINATE or some other unsupported event
                // or could ignore the event and continue
                printf("broadcasting TERMINATE\n");
                MPI_Bcast((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, TERMINATE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                if (strcmp(event, "TERMINATE") != 0) {
                    printf("Invalid event type %s found in file!\n", event);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
 
        // if reached, means fgets() reached EOF and got NULL
        if (ferror(file)) {
            printf("Error reading file.\n");
            MPI_Finalize();
            return -1;
        }
    }
 
    // if current process is a Satellite
    if (rank >= 0 && rank < (n - 1) / 2) {
        MPI_Status status_world;
        int probe_world_flag;
        int leader_election_done = 0;
        metrics_list *metrics = create_metrics_list();
 
        do {
            MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &probe_world_flag, &status_world);
 
            if (probe_world_flag) {
                if (status_world.MPI_TAG == ADD_STATUS && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    st_add_status received_data;
 
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, add_status_datatype, n - 1, ADD_STATUS, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status_world);
 
                    set_st_status(received_data.status);
                    //printf("SATELLITE %d got status %.1f\n", rank, get_st_status());
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == ADD_ST_COORDINATES && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    st_add_coords received_data;
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, st_add_coords_datatype, n - 1, ADD_ST_COORDINATES, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                             &status_world);
                    set_st_coords(received_data.coords);
                    //float *temp = get_st_coords();
                    //printf("SATELLITE %d got COORDINATES %.4f , %.4f , %.4f\n", rank, temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == ADD_METRIC && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    st_add_metric received_data;
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, st_add_metric_datatype, n - 1, ADD_METRIC, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                             &status_world);
                    add_metric(metrics, received_data);
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == START_LELECT_ST && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1 && !
                           leader_election_done) {
                    // start election process
                    //printf("ST %d got start elect with tag %d and flag %d\n", rank, status_world.MPI_TAG, probe_world_flag);
                    MPI_Barrier(comm_group);
                    perform_st_leader_election(n - 1, group_rank, group_size, comm_group, st_lelect_probe_datatype,
                                               st_lelect_reply_datatype);
                    leader_election_done = 1;
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == GS_LEADER && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    int gs_leader_rank;
                    printf("waiting to receive gs\n");
                    MPI_Recv(&gs_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, n - 1, GS_LEADER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status_world);
                    printf("ST %d got gs leader %d\n", rank, gs_leader_rank);
                    set_gs_leader(gs_leader_rank);
                }
            }
        } while (status_world.MPI_TAG != TERMINATE);
 
        // received TERMINATE
        printf("ST %d got terminate.\n", rank);
        destroy_metrics_list(metrics);
    }
    // if it is a Ground Station
    if (rank >= (n - 1) / 2 && rank <= n - 1) {
        // connect message
        // avg temp message
        // status check message
        MPI_Status status_world, status_gs;
        int probe_world_flag, probe_gs_flag;
        int leader_election_done = 0;
 
        do {
            MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &probe_world_flag, &status_world);
 
            if (probe_world_flag) {
                if (status_world.MPI_TAG == CONNECT && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    // Handle CONNECT from coordinator
                    gs_connect received_data;
 
                    // receive connect event from coordinator
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, connect_datatype, n - 1, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status_world);
 
                    printf("GS %d got connect from coordinator\n", rank);
                    // add as parent with group rank, not global rank
                    add_parent_gs(received_data.neighbor_gs_rank % group_size);
                    // add as neighbor as well
                    add_neighbor_gs(received_data.neighbor_gs_rank % group_size);
                    // notify parent that we are its neighbor
                    MPI_Send(&received_data, 1, connect_datatype, received_data.neighbor_gs_rank % group_size, CONNECT,
                             comm_group);
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == ADD_GS_COORDINATES && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    gs_add_coords received_data;
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, gs_add_coords_datatype, n - 1, ADD_GS_COORDINATES, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                             &status_world);
 
                    add_gs_coords(received_data.coords);
                    //float *temp = get_gs_coords();
                    //printf("STATION %d got COORDINATES %.6f , %.6f , %.6f\n", rank, temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
                } else if (status_world.MPI_TAG == ST_LEADER && status_world.MPI_SOURCE == n - 1) {
                    int st_leader_rank;
                    MPI_Recv(&st_leader_rank, 1, MPI_INT, n - 1, ST_LEADER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status_world);
                    printf("GS %d storing leader %d\n", rank, st_leader_rank);
                    set_st_leader(st_leader_rank);
                } else if (!leader_election_done && status_world.MPI_TAG == START_LELECT_GS && status_world.MPI_SOURCE
                           == n - 1) {
                    MPI_Barrier(comm_group);
                    perform_gs_leader_election(n - 1, group_rank, group_size, comm_group);
                    leader_election_done = 1;
                }
            }
 
            MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, comm_group, &probe_gs_flag, &status_gs);
 
            if (probe_gs_flag) {
                if (status_gs.MPI_TAG == CONNECT) {
                    // got CONNECT from another GS
                    gs_connect received_data;
 
                    MPI_Recv(&received_data, 1, connect_datatype, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, CONNECT, comm_group, &status_gs);
 
                    if (status_gs.MPI_SOURCE == received_data.gs_rank % group_size) {
                        // add as child since the event came from the gs_rank source
                        printf("GS neighbor %d got CONNECT from gs_rank %d . Sending ACK to parent %d.\n",
                               rank,
                               received_data.gs_rank, status_gs.MPI_SOURCE + group_size);
                        add_neighbor_gs(status_gs.MPI_SOURCE); // add neighbor with group rank
                        printf("---> GS %d has %d neighbors\n", rank, get_neighbor_count());
                        MPI_Send((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, status_gs.MPI_SOURCE, ACK, comm_group);
                    }
                } else if (status_gs.MPI_TAG == ACK) {
                    // receive ack response from neighbor_gs_rank
                    MPI_Recv((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ACK, comm_group,
                             &status_gs);
                    printf("GS rank %d (local) got ACK from neighbor %d (local). Sending ACK TO COORDINATOR. \n",
                           group_rank,
                           status_gs.MPI_SOURCE % group_size);
                    // gs_rank got ACK from neighbor_gs_rank
                    // send ACK back to the coordinator
                    MPI_Send((void *) 0, 0, MPI_INT, n - 1, ACK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            }
        } while (status_world.MPI_TAG != TERMINATE);
 
        printf("GS %d got terminate.\n", rank);
        //destroy_metrics_list(metrics_list);
    }
 
    MPI_Type_free(&connect_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&add_status_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&st_add_coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&gs_add_coords_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&st_add_metric_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&st_lelect_probe_datatype);
    MPI_Type_free(&st_lelect_reply_datatype);
    MPI_Comm_free(&comm_group);
 
    MPI_Finalize();
 
    return 0;
}


are you sure you always MPI_Recv() after MPI_Probe()?

@GillesGouaillardet you are a godsent, i completely missed that part. I was not consuming the message, for neither START_LELECT_ST nor START_LELECT_GS. This fixed it!
